# loading multiple UIViews into UIScrollView dynamically

Tags: uiview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to load mutiple `UIViews` into `UIScrollView` dynamically - just like posts on facebook. But I don't quite understand how you position the `UIViews` dynamically one after another. Can someone provide me some advice?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use a `UITableView` ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a looping method somewhere on the web. Wanted to thank the source but I forgot where I got it from:

```
- (void)constructPosts:(NSArray*)listOfItems
{
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height*[listOfItems count])];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 200);
    for (int i = 0; i < [listOfItems count]; i++)
    {
        UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        UILabel *test = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 100, 20)];
        [test setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        test.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[listOfItems objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSLog(@"setting up gestures");



        [aView addSubview:test];


        [aView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        frame.origin.y=((frame.size.width+5)*i+5 + (i/3) * 5);
        aView.frame = frame;
        [scrollView addSubview:aView];
    }

}
```